# How to Query data where User Name is Coming several time along with its permission MS Sql Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

hi i am trying to get user id ,name,password,along with its permission but it is listing username ,id ,password several time how to get username ,id,password once along with its permissions my query is,

```
Select U.User_Id,U.User_Name,U.User_Password, PL.PermissionName   from [Inspection].[dbo].[User] U

 right join [Inspection].[dbo].[UsersPermission] UP 

 on U.User_Id=UP.User_Id inner join  PermissionsList PL

 on up.PermissionID=PL.PermissionID 

  where U.User_Id='2';
```

and the result is,

```
User_Id User_Name   User_Password   PermissionName
2     John            123456    View
2     John            123456    Insert
```

Hopes for your suggestion thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select U.User_Id,U.User_Name,U.User_Password
,[permissions]=
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + PermissionName 
    FROM [UsersPermission] iup
    inner join  PermissionsList iPL on iup.PermissionID=iPL.PermissionID         
    WHERE iup.User_Id = u.User_Id  
    order by  PermissionName  
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
from [User] U
where U.User_Id='2';
```

[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13207)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions:

1. Run 2 separate queries. One for user details and second for his permissions.
2. Process this query what you already have.

This is the way how SQL works.

Comment: cant i use sub query with it to do it in one query

Comment: You'll still get multiple rows. This is the way SQL works - don't fight it :) Keep It Simple